# Export/Import/Migrate Rollup Helper Rollups?

Tags: rolluphelper

Is there a simple way to migrate rollups created with Rollup Helper from one org to another? Working through their [documentation](http://rolluphelper.thinkreid.com/home), but can't seem to find anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Export and import is supported

> ### User Interface Approach
>
> #### Generate CSV
>
> 1. Login to your source organization, click the Export Rollups tab.
> 2. Select the rollups you would like to export, click the Export button.
> 3. Click the Download button, this will create a rollups.csv file.
>
> #### Import CSV
>
> 1. Login to your target organization
> 2. Go to Setup -> Data Management -> Import Custom Objects -> Start the Import Wizard.
> 3. Select Rollup Export then click next.
> 4. Upload the rollups.csv file downloaded in step 3, click Next.
> 5. Ensure No is selected then click next.
> 6. Select None for field record owners then click next.
> 7. Choose the file you created earlier and then click next.
> 8. Map type__c to type, RollupOrFilterData__c to Rollup or Filter Data, and filterJobRollupKey__c to filter job rollup key and then
>    click next.
> 9. Ignore the warning and click Import Now! and then click Finish.

see [rollup helper documentation](http://rolluphelper.thinkreid.com/resources/user-guide/rollup-migration-guide) for other import/export options

Answer (score 1):

https://www.passagetechnology.com/lookup-helper-admin-guide#five

**Exporting**:

1. Navigate to the Export Lookup Helper Settings button from the All Lookup Settings page.
2. Click the checkbox next to each lookup that you would like to export and then click on Export Selected. Alternatively, you can also click on the Export All button to select all of them for export.
3. Review all of the lookups that are set to be exported in the Lookups To Be Exported list. Once you have confirmed that they are the lookups that you want to export, select Download. This should open up a save dialog from your browser. Select a folder to save the CSV to and you're done.

If you are not creating parent/category records with your Lookup Helper setting, you can also use any data export tool, such as Data Loader or Dataloader.io, to export your Lookup Helper settings. Below are instructions regarding how to use Data Loader to export Lookup Helper settings:

1. Download and install Data Loader
2. Open Data Loader
3. Click the Export Button and select the Lookup_Helper_Setting__c object from the list (NOT Lookup_Helper_App_Settings__c)
4. Choose your target for extraction
5. Select all fields, add any filters you desire, and click Finish

**Importing**

*Before you import make sure if you have new RollUp fields that they are already created in the object otherwise the import will seem like it will succeed but the Rollups will not be created without any error!

1. Navigate to the setup menu and type Data Import Wizard in the quick find/search bar. Click on the link Data Import Wizard.
2. On the Data Import Wizard page, click on the large green button that says Launch Wizard.
3. You should now be on the Import your Data in to Salesforce page. In the first column, select the tab that says Custom Object. In the list that shows up, scroll down and select Lookup Exports (there should be a green checkmark that shows up).
4. Once the center box shows What do you want to do?, select the top option Add new records. Leave the Match by: and Which User field designates record owners? drop-downs as None.
5. On the third box, you can either select the Lookup Helper export CSV file from your computer and drag it to the Drag CSV file here to upload box, or click on the CSV link and click on Choose File to select the CSV file. Leave the other settings at the default values and click on the green Next button at the bottom right of the page.
6. You should see the Edit Field Mapping: Lookup Exports page. Map the three fields from our CSV file. The first field to map is Type__c to Type. Then map LookupData__c to LookupData and LookupKey__c to LookupKey.
7. Click on the green Next button at the bottom right corner of the page which will take you to the Review & Start Import page. If everything looks good here (3 columns mapped), click on the green Start Import button on the bottom right corner of the page and your lookups and filters should begin importing without any issues.